# How to throw exception if proxy is temporary down and reload browser in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--proxy-server=185.209.177.12:8080'],
    headless: false,
  });
```

I want node.js to reload browser and try again if proxy is down.
The script gets stop executing when proxy is down I want it to continue executing**.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```js
async function run() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ["--proxy-server=185.209.177.12:8080"],
      });
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Proxy temporarily unavailable, retrying...");
      await sleep(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried still not working

Comment: I am using rotating proxies sometime page load fails and I get this error which is why browser crashes (ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED) I want reload my function after a crash

Comment: That's odd. That retry would continue until the connection was successful so I'm not sure how you are trying to implement this.